# Disable logout after x minutes in OSX 10.6.8

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, system-preferences, logout

Every time we change the setting on an iMac running 10.6.8 to not log out after X number of minutes the preference seems to reset to log out after 55 minutes. We don't want the computer to log out as we are running a looping movie and the computer sees this as no activity.

As soon as we change System Preference panes the log out after X minutes resets to being selected and set to 55 minutes. does any one know how to disable this feature/preference? or know what plist needs to be replaced (assuming that the plist is corrupted and will not hold changes)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have solved this issue on your own, if not however, the .plist file you are looking for is */Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist*. Of course you will have to be able to view hidden files to access this particular plist. The value you are looking to change is *com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay* for no auto logout this value should be 0.

If all else fails you should be able to use this command on terminal

```
sudo defaults write GlobalPreferences com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay 0
```

That should override and set the delay

Comment: if this doesn't work  have a look at Caffeine https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12